# how to show the battery icon network icon and so on by default in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I open my flutter app, the phone's battery icon and network icon disappeared.  This is my appbar code:

```
headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
              handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                context,
              ),
              sliver: SliverAppBar(
                title: Text(
                  'Cruise',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                pinned: true,
                expandedHeight: 10.0,
                floating: true,
                snap: true,
                forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                actions: [
                  if (state.currentStoriesType == StoriesType.channels)
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => {dispatch(HomeListActionCreator.onJumpAddChannel())},
                      icon: Icon(Feather.plus),
                    ),
                ],
              )),
        ];
      },
```

how to make the icon show by defult? This is now the icon disappear:

[image]

Comment: did you try to enclose scaffold or body with SafeArea() 
    ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkF0TQJO0bA @Dolphin

Answer (score 1):

use the widget `SafeArea` it will deliver what you wanted.
enclose your top widget in it.